# SQL - Time difference hh:mm:ss

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

My table looks something like this:

[image]

I want to subtract end_date from start_date and it should also subtract hh:mm:ss. The expected output for above should be 00:04:01

I tried multiple ways, but could not figure this out.

How can I do this? I am doing in MySQL

Comment: Specify the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `timestampdiff()` to compute the difference between both `datetime`s in seconds, and then `sec_to_time()` to turn the result to a `time`:

```
sec_to_time(timestampdiff(second, start_date, end_date))
```

Note that the `time` datatype stores values up to about 840 hours.